# Paypal button not working in grails 2.2.1

Tags: grails, paypal

Hi every one i m using Grails 2.2.1 and paypal 0.6.8 in a web app that needs online payment..... here is my code for paypal button

```
  ${p.price}

 <paypal:button
         itemName="${p.price}"
         itemNumber="${p.price}"

         amount="${p.price}"
         buyerId="${session.buyerId}"/>
```

but when i click this button... it redirects to project/paypal/index... i cant understand there isnt even controller named paypal created by plugin .. ... i cant understand where i went wrong can anybody help me with this??

Comment: and also request.payment is coming null... anybody can help me??

Comment: add some materials for your reference: http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/PayPal-Integration-with-Grails     https://grails.org/plugin/paypal